# On itemlist Tap display a panel below the list item Sencha Touch 2

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a list  populating list items from a store. When itemlist tap I just want to show another panel in it. I dont want to use Ext.AccordionLayoutLIst.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new key to the model

```
 { name: 'isOpen', type: 'boolean', defaultValue: false }
```

on itemtap

```
 record.set('isOpen', true)
```

intantly the new part will show.

Here is the template:

```
'<div class="expanded-container">',
    {standard}
    '<tpl if="isOpen">',
        '<div class="newContainer">{onlyShownIfOpen}</div>',
    '</tpl>',
'</div>'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'<div class="search-list-item-container">',
                        '<div class="search-list-details-field">',
                            /*** Other html elements Exist here ****/
                        '</div>',
                        '<div class="search-list-btn-field">',
                            '<input class="play-btn" type="button" value="Play">',
                            '<input class="add-btn"  type="button" value="Add to Playlist">',
                        '</div>',
                    '</div>'
```

Suppose we have an itemTpl(given above) for the list and we want to show "search-list-btn-field" div as a panel only when the corresponding list item is tapped. To make it possible, we have to write css for "search-list-btn-field" class as given below:-

```
.search-list-btn-field {
                display: flex;
                visibility: hidden;
                height: 0px;
}

.selected-search-list-item .search-list-btn-field {
        height: 40px !important;
        visibility: visible !important;
    }
}
```

Finally, we have to add 'selectedCls' property to the config of list..

```
selectedCls: 'selected-search-list-item'
```